# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Sometimes

Tags: android

I am having a weird issues with this error only sometimes. I can recompile are bunch of times to get it to work

```
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.test.test.R$id.img_banner_test
        at com.test.test.Main_Activity.onCreate(Main_Activity.java:46)
```

For this line

```
 ImageView test = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_test);
```

I am using android studio and if I ctrl click on the img_test. Android studio takes me right to my ImageView in the correct layout.

Comment: is the give is the 46th line of `Main_Activity.java`?

Comment: Please post your onCreate() and the AndroidManifest.xml. Does this happen on actual hardware or in the emulator?

Comment: Check if you have not duplicated resources, may be in some library module! And why do you share the line with R.id.img_test and getting error with id.img_banner_test?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I am using

```
class MainActivity implements BaseSetupActivity
```

where `BaseSetupActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` and is in another module, let's call it util.
`BaseSetupActivity` uses resources from util, I think that this happens because of the location of the resources, and their cross-things runtime-time done.

SOLUTIONS:
1) Moving the resources in the `MainActivity`'s module solved my problem.

But I didn't want to move the resources to keep the modules organization consistent.

2) Note that this is only a runtime error. I created the file res/values/ids.xml, template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="linear_layout_inputs" />
    <item type="id" name="linear_layout_outputs" />
    <item type="id" name="button_ok" />
</resources>
```

to remove every "@+id/" from my xml layout files. This worked permanently but I did it manually.

It seems to be an android studio/gradle/XYZ issue as the error is only runtime.

Note that my problem appeared after a Invalidate+Restart.